# Maximize function subject to condition

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, syntax, maximum

What commands should I use in *Mathematica* to obtain the maximum or minimum of a function subject to conditions?

For example, find the maximum of the following function?

$\qquad T=\sqrt[3]{2\,x+5} + \sqrt[3]{2\,y+5} , x > 0 ,y > 0 , x + y=3$

Comment: `Maximize` -- just search for it in the docs.

Comment: BTW, people here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Edited ... ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the maximum

```
Maximize[
  {Power[2 x + 5, (3)^-1] + Power[2 y + 5, (3)^-1], x > 0, y > 0, x + y == 3},
  {x, y}]
```

> `{4, {x -> 3/2, y -> 3/2}}`

For the minimum, Mathematica says there no minimum on the line `x + y == 3` that is a minimum with the open set of the search space.

Comment: ,thanks, it is not clear to me the use of Power in replacement of the cubic roots of each expression, please clarify

Comment: I get it. Thank You